# How to print QR code using EPL commands from Zebra GC420t printer

Tags: barcode, zebra-printers, epl

I am using EPL commands to print barcodes(Zebra GC420t).
Now i need to print QR code using EPL commands(Zebra GC420t).
Please help to find out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

*Suggested: **[EPL Programming Guide](https://www.servopack.de/support/zebra/EPL2_Manual.pdf#page=81)***

As seen on the docs, QR codes can be printed with the b (barcode) command:

```
Format: b(x-position),(y-position),Q,(model),"(qr code data)"
```

So, if you wanted to print a QR code with a "hello" value it would be something like this

```
b264,130,Q,m2,"hello"
```